# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' althouth the model seems to be installed

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pycharm

On the code:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
```

I get the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I'm using linux Ubuntu as OS and I'm working with Python 3.6.

To check wether matplotlib is installed I tried the 2 linux instructions on the command line:

```
apt-cache search matplotlib
```

and

```
sudo apt search matplotlib
```

Both of them were showing results, so I think that matplotlib is installed.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,font
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont

root = tk.Tk()

import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
```

Pls. help.

Comment: Why are not using `pip`? Is that package installed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You have two pythons installed on your machine, one is the standard python that comes with Mac OSX and the second is the one you installed with ports (this is the one that has matplotlib installed in its library, the one that comes with macosx does not).

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Is the standard mac python and since it doesn't have matplotlib you should always start your script with the one installed with ports.

If python your_script.py works then change the #! to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Or put the full path to the python interpreter that has the matplotlib installed in its library.

Comment: He is using Ubuntu (linux), not Mac OSX

Comment: use this:   
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib

Comment: Sorry, I've neglected the first line. Its:    #!/usr/bin/python3.6    and I'm using Linux Ubuntu - Yes.

Comment: Thanks brkcnplt. It seems that the problem is resolved. Now it doesn't find the font family. The program doesn't work yet, but now it's because it doesn't find the font-family.